# On Action or Controller Change Callback in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp

I have come across a problem with I am having a edit form, so what I want to achieve is if user edits an item it gets locked so other user can not edit this item at the same time. I want something that when user clicks on other link it unlocks the item. Please don't suggest on unload because it will not not work on iOS Safari.

If anyone can give me steps/concept that would help a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a couple columns to your table such as 'locked' and `locking_timestamp`.

If a record is currently "locked" you can make it inaccessible by others and you can use the `locking_timestamp` column to only allow a particular record to be locked for a specified duration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same method used by drupal :
compare the date of last change before saving the row to detect if the row has been changed by an other user
see :http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/node-editing-concurrency-in-drupal.html